# How can DPDK ACL library handle more than 16(RTE_ACL_MAX_CATEGORIES) categories?

Tags: dpdk

I'm using DPDK 20.08 and I need to copy and distribute packets to many targets, which involves the multi-category parallel classification feature on DPDK ACL. But according to the documentation and source code, one can only set up to RTE_ACL_MAX_CATEGORIES categories, which is 16. If I want to set more than 16, do I have to use at least 2 ACL context and lookup one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question> `I need to copy and distribute packets to many targets`

Caution> If the original content of the Ethernet frame is not modified at all, then one can use `mbuf->ref_cnt` to circumvent the overhead of mbuf copy. But if packet content will be different on each interface (such as dstmac or valn or ip headers) the one has to duplicate the packet. If mbuf->ref_cnt is used one can not use the NIC offload `RX_MBUF_FAST_FREE` too.

***Solution 1:***
Depending upon the support of SIMD on the hardware (CPU) one can use `RTE_ACL_CLASSIFY_AVX512X32`. This allows 32 flow parallel lookup to be processed on CPU such skylake, cascadelake and icelake. refer [Section 53.1.3](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/packet_classif_access_ctrl.html) for more details.

***Solution 2 (If there is no support for SIMD AVX512):***
is it worth to run all 16 or 32 flow lookup then copy mbuf into multiple targets, then modify the contents for each interface?

My suggestion is to use the HW (NIC or ASIC) or using SW (rx bridge driver) to create mirror on ingress traffic and sent to separate RX queue. By using separate CPU threads smaller ACL tables can be used.

***Solution 3 (If there is no support for SIMD AVX512):***
One can start of modifying `lib/acl/rte_acl.h` for `#define RTE_ACL_MAX_CATEGORIES  16` to `#define RTE_ACL_MAX_CATEGORIES  32` as starting point of reference. There will be many other areas as `mask` which will also requires modification and support. Personally I do not recommend this option as it creates more out of tree dependency and needs to spend more time debugging the other issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.